# POI XSSF : javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found - Error

Tags: eclipse, apache-poi, xssf

I'm having this problem in a RCP Aplication.

A little Introduccion.
My App is build with Eclispe Indigo 32 bits.
I have two projects, one is mainly a library container, and the other project is the main application, and it have a relation to the Library Project, all in one Elipse Workspace.

A few year ago, I was reading xls files, but now I need to read and write xlsx, and xlsm files.

So I downloaded all POI binary files (poi-bin-3.16-20170419).

I managed to add jar files in library Project, so the source filesgive me NO errors.

But when I run the application I get this error:

```
javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.EventFactory not found
```

I try to reorder jar files in "Java Build Path"-> "Order and Export", but the error is the same.

I'll add some screen captures.

[image: log console]

Here I try to put Stax-api-xx.jar first, because javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder is in two libs, jre_1.6 and stax-api !

[image: Java Build Path]

[image: finding javax.xml.stream.FactiryFinder]

Where is the error ?

A sneak peak of my workspace:

[image: workspace]

Best regards

Comment: I created a Snippet of code in the project, and debug as Java Aplication, and it works fine ! with the same imports, and lines of code. So it's clearly a problem in the order of priority when Eclipse load libraries, How can I check the order of jar files loaded un memory ?

Comment: I downgraded JRE to 1.5 and download POI 3.10, witch is the las that support java 1.5. Re-order some jar libraries, and looks like is working. Just an issue with access restriction to a method... but if I change access rules, it works, the problem is that eclipse rewrite that rule every restart.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the javax/xml folder from local repository and try building the project again.
This will solve the issue in some cases.